# As a Spaniard, can I enter Chile with no return flight ticket?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, chile, spanish-language, return-tickets

I am going to travel around South America with no clear route yet, I just know I will start in Chile.

I have seen that it is possible to stay there for 3 months without problems if I had a return flight. My plan is to go to Argentina afterwards, but I do not know when or how, in less than 3 months for sure.

Would it cause problems trying to enter the country because I have no ticket to leave it?

Comment: A quick check of https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/CL-Chile-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm  resulted in a warning ‘Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry’.

Comment: As a possible solution, I have found that it is possible to buy some cheap bus ticket between two locations which are close from each other but in different countries. Ideally this should be bought for the longest period possible (some permissions might be given just for the duration of the trip), so close to the 90 days allowed in this case.